# Canon 70D vs Canon 760D

Tags: canon, canon-70d

I have been looking to buy a Canon 760D because of its amazing features that it offers in comparison to the currently available list of DSLR's out there. I have previously owned a 550D and had a great experience with that. However the city where I am trying to buy it from is Dammam and they do not have the 760D model available. The only model they have is either Canon 750D (which seems like a bit of a downgrade to me) or Canon 70D. I don't intend to buy the 750D because I feel 760D would be a better choice but because of its non-availability, I was considering going for the 70D. I know the fact that its the lens that counts when it comes to DSLR's:)

I have checked out the reviews and differences [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_MQpaFLuAkU) between 760D and 70D however because its a bit more pricier than the 760D, I would like to know if there are that many significant differences worth paying the extra money for. Could the users of these two models comment on what their experience has been with these two models?

Cheers.

**Update:**

Apart from the weight, battery life and megapixel differences, I see that the NFC feature is not included in the 70D model. Would that mean that I cannot use the 70D to touch and send my pictures to another device? WiFi is included in both but how would not having NFC work out?

**Usage:**

I usually use my DSLR for food photography, portraits and landscapes at times. I already have a 50 mm f/1.8 lens with me.

Comment: Either camera might be the right choice *for you*. Unless you tell us about what you plan to do with it and what specific features you consider "amazing" it is difficult for anyone to advise you which is better *for you*.

Comment: Hi michael, I have updated my question. Please check and let me know.

Comment: Note that right now, at least in the US, the 70D is selling for slightly *less* than the Rebel T6s/760D.

Comment: The difference between the 70D and 760D is not really prosumer vs. entry level (that would be either the 70D or 760D vs. the 750D). This is borne out by the 760D's direct successor being named the 77D (rather than the 810D).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The use case that will reveal the most separation between the two is with longer focal length lenses that have wide apertures. The 70D includes the option to calibrate the camera to individual lenses via *Auto Focus Micro Adjustment (AFMA)*, the 760D/Rebel T6s does not.

AFMA allows the end user to adjust for the differences in manufacturing tolerances between a lens and a camera. Without AFMA the options when you get a camera/lens "mismatch" are to either keep swapping lenses until you find one that "matches" your camera or send both the camera and lens to a Canon service center to have them matched. The first option means every time you replace your camera you may well have to swap all of your lenses as well!

If you ever plan on shooting with a lens past about 135mm that has an aperture of f/2.8, you'll likely need this feature to get the most out of your lens. The longer the focal length, the slower the f-number where focus adjustment becomes critical. At 400mm even at f/4 or f/5.6 you would benefit from AFMA capability.

Additionally, the 70D has better environmental resistance (weather sealing), and a larger (.95x vs. .82x magnification; 98% vs. 95% coverage), brighter viewfinder that uses a pentaprism rather than a pentamirror like the 760D. It shoots bursts at 7 fps vs. 5fps, has a faster top shutter speed of 1/8000 sec vs. 1/4000 sec, and the battery is rated for 920 vs. 440 shots.

The 760D/Rebel T6s has more resolution (24MP vs. 20MP), *slightly* higher dynamic range (12.0EV vs 11.6EV) and *ever-so-slightly* more color depth (22.6 bits vs. 22.5 bits). It also has an RGB+IR light meter that Canon seems to be putting in many of their cameras recently while the older 70D has the monochromatic 63 segment meter that served almost the entire Canon line prior to the introduction of RGB+IR metering with the original 1D X in 2012. If you'll find yourself shooting in tricky lighting and don't have the experience to know how to adjust exposure for things such as a portrait subject wearing light colored clothing or a landscape with a lot of green in it then a camera with RGB metering will be very helpful finding proper exposure.

Comment: Thanks Michael, that's great to know the technical difference in that.

Comment: Hi Michael, what about the NFC aspect of it?

Comment: Obviously the 760D has it and the 70D doesn't. I don't personally consider it a factor at all since I shoot all my images as raw files and edit them before *anyone* sees them. LOL. The 70D has WiFi that as far as I see can do most of the same things. It's just a different protocol. Kind of like WiFi vs. Bluetooth. WiFi is a little more difficult to set up, but also offers more customization. To me that has nothing to do with which camera will take better pictures.