# Canon Digic 6 and Digic 7

Tags: canon, equipment-recommendation

Canon 80 D with DIGIC 6 was released in Feb 2016. Canon 77D with DIGIC 7 was released in Feb 2017.Does that make the canon 77D better than canon 80 D eventhough 80D has better features and is more expensive. What is the effect of a better sensor?

Comment: Note that DIGIC is Canon's name for their image processing pipeline, *not* for the sensor.

Comment: For all practical purposes, these two cameras have the same sensor. They have different processors and also vary with regard to other features. The comparison is very similar to the Rebel T7i/800D vs. 77D or 80D.

Comment: Choice of a camera is extremely dependent upon the intended usage, particularly in the case of cameras as similar as the 77D and 80D. It really depends upon what you specifically intend to do with your camera which would be "better." Both have advantages and disadvantages compared to the other.

Comment: It's also very similar to a comparison of the [70D (the 80D's direct predecessor) vs. the EOS Rebel T6s/760d (the 77D's direct predecessor)](https://photo.stackexchange.com/a/77930/15871).

Answer (score 1):

**TL;DR: Choose 80D if you want 100% viewfinder coverage or need AFMA, choose 77D if you need high ISO and light weight. I would choose 77D.**

Camera bodies have several main features:

- Viewfinder. More expensive bodies have larger, brighter viewfinders with more coverage. The Canon 80D has 0.95X magnification with 100% coverage, whereas the 77D has 0.82X magnification with 95% coverage.¹ The 80D also has a brighter (and heavier) pentaprism while the 77D has a cheaper pentamirror.
- Control of mirror and shutter. More expensive bodies have independent controls of these functions (two motors), meaning e.g. mirror lockup becomes possible. You need this feature if you are concerned about vibration on a tripod. Both 77D and 80D seem to have mirror lockup.
- Autofocus. More expensive bodies have autofocus on lower light and generally more AF points. Also, some Canon models have dual pixel AF for better focusing in live view mode. Both 77D and 80D have dual pixel AF and 45 cross-type points. I assume AF features on these models are similar.
- [AFMA](https://photo.stackexchange.com/a/77930/15871). The 80D has it, the 77D does not. This is most impactful when using wide aperture and long focal length lenses.
- Burst. 80D offers 7fps, 77D offers 6fps. Not much difference in practice.
- Image sensor. I'd be concerned about low-noise performance at high-ISO, instead of being concerned about megapixel count. All recent sensors contain plenty of megapixels. 77D has higher ISO (25600 as opposed to 16000 on 80D).
- Weight. 77D has much less weight, so choose it if you need less weight.

There are also some other useful features such as Wi-Fi connectivity to operate the camera remotely using your phone, but both 77D and 80D have that feature.

<sub>¹ At the indicated eye relief for each camera, the viewfinder in the 80D (19mm eye relief) will show approximately 100% of the field of view at an apparent size of 21.185 x 13.708 millimeters. The 77D (22mm eye relief) will show approximately 95% of the camera's field of view at an apparent size of 17.3717 x 11.6011 millimeters.</sub>

Comment: The 80D and 77D have essentially the same AF system and imaging sensors (though there does seem to be a slight difference in the analog amplification settings between the two). For me the lack of AFMA with the 77D would be a deal breaker.

Comment: In practice, neither camera is probably going to be acceptable past about ISO 6400. Their performance [as measured by DxO Mark](https://www.dxomark.com/Cameras/Compare/Side-by-side/Canon-EOS-77D-versus-Canon-EOS-80D___1156_1076) is almost indistinguishable. Press 'Measurements → SNR 18% → Screen' to see the actual measurements. Also compare 'Dynamic Range', 'Tonal Range', and 'Color Sensitivity'.